# How to detect that textDidChange: on UISearchBar was triggered by dictation

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I am currently facing a problem related to `UISearchBar` and dictation support. I have to trigger some filter logic when the text of the search bar changes. This logic has to be triggered either the change was done by keyboard typing or dictation.

Now here is my problem: If I end dictation in search bar, the `textDidChange` method is triggered immediately (while speech recognition is running). After recognition is done, the method is triggered again with the correct string.

How do I detect that the first call of the method was triggered by the start of speech recognition? Because I have to avoid execution of my logic in this case.

I already tried to inspect the `searchText` parameter that is passed to the method. But the results are kind of suspicious.

If I add this code to `searchBar:textDidChange:`

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    NSLog(@"SearchText [%@] - SearchTextLength [%i] - SearchTextEquals [%i]", searchText, searchText.length, [searchText isEqualToString:@""]);
}
```

The I am getting this log result:

```
SearchText [￼] - SearchTextLength [1] - SearchTextEquals [0]
```

I am stuck at this point. How can the `searchText` be [] (empty) but has a length of 1? Is there another way to detect that speech recognition is still running?

Comment: Seems like searchText is not empty. It has one white space. That's why length of string is 1

Comment: @Iducool I already tried this ... `[searchText isEqualToString:@" "]` also evaluates to 0 in the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem: detect that speech dictation is still running and processing the voice input.

It's exactly like you are describing: from the *textDidChange* you get an **empty** NSString with **length=1**

In my case, my solution was to take the first char of the text (if available) and check it's integer value. Apparently, the value of the "processing voice input" is always **-17**,

I know that is not a perfect solution, but it works. If someone has a better solution, please share it :)

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    BOOL atLeastOneChar = searchText.length > 0;
    BOOL speechRecognitionOngoing;

    if (atLeastOneChar) {
       // Checking if the user used the dictation feature. 
       // A char of value -17 is always returned as text while processing the voice.
       // So if the first char is == -17 it means the dictationg is going on.

       const char firstChar = *text.UTF8String;
       NSInteger processingDictationSpeechChar = -17;
       if (firstChar == processingDictationSpeechChar) {
           // --> speech recognition is ongoing!
           speechRecognitionOngoing = YES;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The -17 detected in this answer is actually the first byte of the UNICODE Object Replacement Character.  If you detect it, you have to detect the whole multibyte character, which in this case is `\xef\xbf\xbc`.  The -17 is the `\xef` byte.  If you only detect the first byte you'll get false positives for things such as hangul and katana characters and international currency symbols - eg Yen is `\xef\xbf\xa5`.  The character can also appear at any point in the string, so you have to iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect dictation in progress with `[UITextInputMode currentInputMode].primaryLanguage;` - this returns `dictation` while dictation is in progress, because the grey overlay with the wave while dictation is in progress is a keyboard from the point of view of the app.  You can also detect a change by listening for `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification`.